# MapSignalR is missing with vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

How can i add owin and signal r to the .net framework 4.0. I am using vs 2010

Comment: Have you searched for the error? I've found several other questions from people with the same error.

Comment: I have got a solution to add older version

Comment: I have implemented notification with signal r. But the notification count is getting updated on the page where i am sendign the notification..If i have another window opened it is not getting updated.Any idea to resolve